# IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical when calling existing folder

Tags: java, uri, java.nio.file

I'm doing this:

```
private boolean createCopy(String targetDirectory, String[] dataSet, String fileName, boolean overwrite) throws IOException, URISyntaxException
{
    fileName = "file:" + fileName.replace(" ","%20");
    URI uri = new URI("file:" + targetDirectory);
    Path dPath = Paths.get(uri);
    //code
 }
```

And I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsUriSupport.fromUri(WindowsUriSupport.java:122)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.getPath(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:92)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:138)
...
```

At the

```
Path dPath = Paths.get(uri);
```

line. Anyone having any idea why that is? `targetDirectory` is just a simple folder, neither a `JAR` nor a `WAR` file  ; if I do away with the

```
URI uri = new URI("file:" + targetDirectory);
```

I just get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "DRIVE_LETTER" not installed
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:147)
...
```

`"DRIVE_LETTER"` ends up being something like "C" or "D" or "E". It's the drive that `targetDirectory`is located on.

EDIT:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    Path path = null;
    try
    {
        Paths.get(new URI("file:E://HTML%20Processor//test//copies//"));
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Throws exactly the same exceptions, since you are wondering about the exact call.

EDIT: Putting the file on any other drive makes no difference; USB or SATA drive makes no difference either.

Comment: so,can you kindly provide us with the call to this method ?

Comment: can you tell exactly what is your target directory path. Also if possible provide complete method. and values passed to it. java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException means the drive is not accessible. Do you have the specified drive path mounted on the machine this code is running.

Comment: Provided a simple method that throws the same error!

Comment: The drive location is accessible just like always; I can move files around, copy, delete. System drive or not makes no difference either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be file:// not file:

Comment: Actually file:// lead to other errors. file:/ was the solution for me.